# It's my disk in bad shape? (e2fsck vs smartctl)

Tags: hard-drive, fsck, smart

After an electric shortage one disk lost some data. Because I have backup I simply and there was a lot of non-important data, I decided to destroy the partition and start fresh.

The disk work ok for some days, and suddenly all the information was gone...

Checking on smartctl looks everything is ok, but running fsck (actually I tried with esfsck) show tons of errors.

This is smartctl output:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.13.0-41-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba MG07ACA... Enterprise Capacity HDD
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MG07ACA12TE
Serial Number:    40Q0A00DF6DH
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 a18c95ac8
Firmware Version: 4402
User Capacity:    12,000,138,625,024 bytes [12.0 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri May 13 09:10:32 2022 IDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (1237) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       2597
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       341
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   082   082   000    Old_age   Always       -       7236
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       341
 23 Helium_Condition_Lower  0x0023   100   100   075    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 24 Helium_Condition_Upper  0x0023   100   100   075    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       332
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3507
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       39 (Min/Max 19/45)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2097152
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       2407
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       594
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA      MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0  23437770751  Not_testing
    2        0            0  Not_testing
    3        0            0  Not_testing
    4        0            0  Not_testing
    5        0            0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

And this is the end of `sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdb`
Full file is here: https://ghostbin.com/T5ZQ7

```
Error writing block 1394 (Invalid argument).  Ignore error? yes

Error writing block 1395 (Invalid argument).  Ignore error? yes

Error writing block 1396 (Invalid argument).  Ignore error? yes

Error writing block 1397 (Invalid argument).  Ignore error? yes

Error writing block 1390 (Invalid argument).  Ignore error? yes

Error writing block 1391 (Invalid argument).  Ignore error? yes

Error writing block 1392 (Invalid argument).  Ignore error? yes

Error writing file system info: Input/output error

/dev/sdb: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
```

There is an issue? It's the disk faulty?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Friendly reminder: if you have important data that is critical, also keep a copy that is physically located somewhere else (ideally somewhere far away) so that if your device gets fried your data will be safe. Also, [RAID is not a backup](https://serverfault.com/a/2897/870242). Lastly, a (good) UPS may have helped here. Sadly, I have no idea if the drive is safe to use or not. But those are some tips for the future!

Answer (score 2):

Power supply was not ok and when several disk started to do intensive work, the communication started to fail.